# Difference between initializations stringstream.str( a_value ) and stringstream << a_value

Tags: c++, initialization, concatenation, stringstream

Consider:

```
std::string        s_a, s_b;

std::stringstream  ss_1, ss_2;

// at this stage:
//     ss_1 and ss_2 have been used and are now in some strange state
//     s_a and s_b contain non-white space words

ss_1.str( std::string() );
ss_1.clear();

ss_1 << s_a;
ss_1 << s_b;

// ss_1.str().c_str() is now the concatenation of s_a and s_b, 
//                    <strike>with</strike> without space between them

ss_2.str( s_a );
ss_2.clear();

// ss_2.str().c_str() is now s_a

ss_2 << s_b;  // line ***

// ss_2.str().c_str() the value of s_a is over-written by s_b 
// 
// Replacing line *** above with "ss_2 << ss_2.str() << " " << s_b;"
//                    results in ss_2 having the same content as ss_1.
```

Questions:

1. What is the difference between stringstream.str( a_value ); and
   stringstream << a_value;  and, specifically, why does the first not
   allow concatenation via << but the second does?
2. <strike>Why did ss_1 automatically get  white-space between s_a and s_b, but
   do we need to explicitly add white space in the line that  could
   replace line ***:  `ss_2 << ss_2.str() << " " << s_b;`?</strike>

Comment: In your example, your strings are empty. What do you mean by `automatically get white-space between s_a and s_b`?

Comment: @JesseGood `//     s_a and s_b contain non-white space words`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem you're experiencing is because `std::stringstream` is constructed by default with `ios_base::openmode mode = ios_base::in|ios_base::out` which is a *non-appending* mode.

You're interested in the output mode here (ie: `ios_base::openmode mode = ios_base::out`)

`std::basic_stringbuf::str(const std::basic_string<CharT, Traits, Allocator>& s)` operates in two different ways, depending on the `openmode`:

1. `mode & ios_base::ate == false`: (ie: **non-appending** output streams):

   `str` will set `pptr() == pbase()`, so that subsequent output will **overwrite the characters copied from s**
2. `mode & ios_base::ate == true`: (ie: **appending** output streams):

   `str` will set `pptr() == pbase() + s.size()`, so that subsequent output will be **appended** to the last character copied from s

(Note that this **appending** mode is new since c++11)

More details can be found [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_stringbuf/str).

If you want the *appending* behaviour, create your `stringstream` with `ios_base::ate`:

```
std::stringstream ss(std::ios_base::out | std::ios_base::ate)
```

Simple example app here:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>

void non_appending()
{
    std::stringstream ss;
    std::string s = "hello world";

    ss.str(s);
    std::cout << ss.str() << std::endl;

    ss << "how are you?";
    std::cout << ss.str() << std::endl;
}

void appending()
{
    std::stringstream ss(std::ios_base::out | std::ios_base::ate);
    std::string s = "hello world";

    ss.str(s);
    std::cout << ss.str() << std::endl;

    ss << "how are you?";
    std::cout << ss.str() << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
    non_appending();
    appending();

    exit(0);
}
```

This will output in the 2 different ways as explained above:

```
hello world
how are you?
hello world
hello worldhow are you?
```

Comment: Another way to do this, without modifying the `openmode`, is to seek to the end of the stream before insertion. `ss.str(s); ss.seekp(0, std::ios_base::end); ss << "how are you?";`

Comment: Thanks;  minor tweak:  In non_appending(), if the first initialization is make longer, say, <code>std::string s = "A very long hello world!";</code> then the second line of output would be:  "how are you?hello world!"

Comment: @user1823664 - to understand what is happening here you need to understand that the `stringstream's` `streambuffer` uses internal pointers to store positions in the buffer. `str()` uses these pointers to create a new `std::string` - and depending on where `egptr` or `pptr` are you'll get a string built from these.

Answer (score 3):

Suggest you read stringstream reference: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_stringstream

`std::stringstream::str()` Replaces the contents of the underlying string

`operator<<` Inserts data into the stream.

Comment: Still doesnt explain why `str()` followed by `<<` has such behavior, unless I am misreading something

Comment: The other thing is that after using `str()`, ththings get out of sync. For example, using `str()` on a new instance, followed by `operator<<` will insert the second part at the beginning, overwriting the first part. http://ideone.com/OPR9Ps

Comment: He's asking why calling `operator<<` **after** using `str` to replace the contents doesn't **append** to the end - and the answer is because `openmode` doesn't have `ate` set